# Have to show the Correct time, Currently, incorrect or hardcoded time is shown

Tags: javascript

Currently, incorrect or hardcoded time is shown with this code:

```
details.banner ={};
let hours = moment.duration(moment(lastStage.timeStamp) - moment(firstStage.timeStamp)).asHours();
if(lastStage.showBanner && hours <= 24){
   let timeInfo;
   if(hours <= 1){
        timeInfo = " In an hour.";
   } else {
        timeInfo = " in " + Math.trunc(hours) + " hour(s)";
   }
   details.banner.message = "Amount credited of ₹ " + amount.toFixed(2) + timeInfo;
}
return details;
```

**We have to show correct time now using below details:**

1. If gets credited in 0-1 minute
   We have credited you an amount of x in just x minute.
2. If  gets credited in 2-59 minutes
   We have credited you an amount of x in just x minutes.
3. If  gets credited in 1 hour

We have credited you an amount of x in 1 hour.

4. If  credited more than 1 hour.

We have credited you an amount of x in x hours.

Initially I am sending hardcoded value but now have to send correct time acc to conditions. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

By using [momentJS](https://momentjs.com/) you can easily done it.

Below snippet consist of momentJS's [duration method](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/08-durations/00-intro/), [difference method](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/07-difference/), [humanize](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/08-durations/03-humanize/) and [relative-time-threshold](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/07-customization/13-relative-time-threshold/).

Just replacing the values of `currenttime` to `lastStage.timeStamp` and `timeInput` to `firstStage.timeStamp`.

```js
function getTimeDiff(timeInput){
  //You may directly use fromNow() to compare the input time with current time.
  //const diff = moment(timeInput, "YYYYMMDDHHmmss").fromNow();
  
  //We will be hardcoding the currentime so that the diff is constant everytime when this snippet run.
  const currenttime = moment("20230214123000","YYYYMMDDHHmmss").format();
  timeInput = moment(timeInput,"YYYYMMDDHHmmss").format();
  
  //Refer to momentJS Documentation on diff,humanize,relativeTimeThreshold usage.
  const diff = moment.duration(moment(currenttime).diff(timeInput)).humanize(true,{
    ss: 1,
    s: 60,
    m: 60,
    h: 24,
    d: 7,
    w: 4,
    M: 12
  });
  
  console.log(`We have credited you an amount of X just ${diff}.`);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <ol>
    <li>Within <button type="button" onclick="getTimeDiff('20230214122930')">30 seconds</button></li>
    <li>Within <button type="button" onclick="getTimeDiff('20230214122800')">2 minutes</button></li>
    <li>Within <button type="button" onclick="getTimeDiff('20230214113000')">1 hour</button></li>
    <li>Within <button type="button" onclick="getTimeDiff('20230214063000')">6 hours</button></li>
    <li>Within <button type="button" onclick="getTimeDiff('20230207123000')">7 days</button></li>
    <li>Within <button type="button" onclick="getTimeDiff('20221214123000')">2 months</button></li>
  </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if i dont want to hard code the `currentime`.  @JoshuaOOi

Comment: The currenttime is hardcoded to let you see the result in the snippets. If you dont want hard code it, the just add it as a argument to pass together into the function when the funcion is called.

Answer (score 1):

You just should convert what you said in english, but with if. With else if, we prevent to have big if to be sure of below values.

```js
function format(time) {
  if(time <= 1) // 0 or 1 min
    return time + " minute";
  else if(time <= 59) // 2 until 59 min
    return time + " minutes";
  else if(time <= 119) // 1 hour to 1.99 hours
    return "1 hour";
  else {
    return Math.trunc(time / 60) + " hours";
  }
}

console.log(format(1));
console.log(format(15));
console.log(format(60));
console.log(format(130));
```

In my example, I gave values as seconds. Simply divide/multiply according to the base time you have.

Comment: Use `asSeconds()` (instead of `asHours()`) then you will have the time as seconds instead of hour, and you will be able to use it as expected